# CSS Static Background banner

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I bought a theme in envatomarket and here is the [link](http://themeforest.net/item/city-government-theme-for-government-agencies/4558198). Now I have a problem with the background banner. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the background of the banner is like a collage of pictures and it is cropped according to the size of screen but the original image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fob8z.jpg). Since it is `bootstrap`, the image will resize according to the size of the screen. But what if I want to show the full image in the background as it is the link? Here are the codes:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <section class="banner-bg">
 //more html
 </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
max-width:100%;
}

.banner-bg { 
background:url(../images/main-bg.jpg) no-repeat top center;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
```

Is there a way that whatever the size of the screen is, the full image will still be visible and not like of the screenshot above? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

background-size:100 100;